# How To Download images & Store in SDcard in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

How To Download images & Store in SDcard in Blackberry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Open http-connection to the image resource.
- [Open InputStream instance](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/J2ME/HttpConnection.htm) over this connection
- Use [BlackBerry FileConnections
  API](http://blackberry-tips-bikas.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-read-write-and-copy-file-in.html) to create file
- Read the image to the stream and write this stream to
  the file